# PHP how to treat string as binary number

Tags: php, binary, type-conversion

I wanted to find how to make the sum of 2 binary numbers.

Problem is they don't have the leading 0b prefix.

I can do this with bindec(), and back to binary with decbin(), but it looks really useless to convert from binary to decimal and to convert it back in binary. Plus, it's said to have poor performances ( seen this on SO somewhere else ).

Is there a solution to avoid these functions ?
For example, how to do the sum, in binary, of :

```
$a = "11";
$b = "01";
```

Thanks !

Edit : to be clearer, with binSum a user function, I want :

```
echo binSum($a,$b);
```

print :

```
100
```

Edit2 : For help here's what the function binSum looks like for now :

```
function binSum( $a, $b ) {
    return decbin(bindec($a) + bindec($b));
}
```

Edit3 : made clearer reasons why I asked

Comment: *"it's said to have really poor perf"* Where did you see that? It's the function you need. Just use it.

Comment: You mean "binary representation": `printf('%08b', 3);`

Comment: @Olivier somewhere on another question on Stack.
Well, we think we absolutely need  function 'till we find something which match exactly our case.
As I convert from the format I want to a format I don't want, to convert back again to the one I want, there's a significant place to something better :)

Comment: @HonkderHase Let's try with my input :
`printf('%08b', "11");`
=> 00001011
So, no !
I want to be able to have :
`echo binSum($a,$b);`
=> 100
With binSum one of my functions.

Comment: You're dismissing the obvious and simple solution because of somebody else's conjecture. Implement bindec(), get your unit tests to pass, and don't worry about micro optimizations. If, at some extremely unlikely point in the future, you observe an actual measurable performance issue in your specific production context, then you can come back and refactor.

Comment: @AlexHowansky
Actually I think it's shame to need intermediate decimal conversion as soon as mathematically we don't need it. Perhaps I'm wrong somewhere !

Comment: When you ran a profiler on your app to find the performance bottlenecks, how close to the top of the list was this line with bindec()?

Comment: Ok. Perhaps my question is not well asked.
The reason why I asked it is not only perf, primarily it's because we seem to use an unnecessarily conversion.
That's not on app, that's only a little case to go further in my understanding, and practise of PHP. But my investigations show that as soon as PHP automatically convert to a decimal base a binary number ( 0bXX ), my question looks pointless. But if i didn't asked myself, and SO community, I wouldn't have found it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it looks like that :

```
var_dump( 0b11 );
```

Gives :

```
int(3)
```

So, as soon as internally PHP do not record numbers in binary format, but will convert it to decimal, my question look pointless, because it will always do this :

bin numbers -> convert to dec numbers -> sum

So even when we read the code, we can think it's useless to convert binary to decimal then come back to binary after some operation, it won't add any operation to what PHP does internally.

Edit : as @AlexHowansky said in comments, it's perhaps non-significant in term of performance. Tests will be added.